# T-SQL Add new column in existing table and fill with value from two another existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `test` with the following columns: `id`, `startDate`, `stopDate`, `startOvertime`, `stopOvertime`.

`startDate` and `stopDate` are of type datetime and `startOvertime`, `stopOvertime` are of type `time(7)`.

I want to create a new column with the date portion from `stopDate` and the time portion from `startOvertime` and copy that into a newly created column `test-fill`.

If I use formula (stopDate, startOvertime) then the value of the new datetime column is not right. Any proposals?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you always want the new column with this information, then you can use a computed column:

```
alter table test add test-fill as
    (cast(cast(startDate as date) as datetime) + cast(overtime as datetime));
```

This doesn't actually add a new column.  It just computes the values when you need them.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
alter table [table-name] add [test-fill] datetime

update [table-name]
set [test-fill] = cast(startDate as date) + cast(stopOvertime as datetime)
```

First we add column to the table, then we update created cells with data.

Comment: in this case is not get only date from startDate but datetime with his time and added time from stopOvertime

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD NEWCOL DATETIME;
UPDATE TEST
SET NEWCOL = CAST((CAST(CAST(stopDate as date) as varchar(10))+' '+CAST(CAST(startOvertime as time) as varchar(10))) as DATETIME);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.